# Oracle 11g - Plain query with large data is performing slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have 3 tables

TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_TRANS_OP - 30 million records

TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_POS_OP - 30 million records

TB_ETD_ENUMERATION  - Master table with 100 records

We are executing below query to fetch 20 records only

```
SELECT * FROM   (   SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER () CNT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REPORTING_TIMESTAMP DESC NULLS LAST) RN,
    INNER_QRY.*          FROM
    (SELECT MARRS_MSG_ID,
      OWN_OR_DEL_REP,
      ACTION,
      UTI_VALUE UTI,
      EN.DESCRIPTION REPORTING_PARTY,
      OP.REPORTING_PARTY REPORTING_PARTY_CODE,
      PRIMARY_ASSET_CLASS ASSET_CLASS,

      TRADE_PARTY_INTR INTERNAL_TRADE_REF_ID,
      TRANSACTION_REFERENCE_ID TRANSACTION_REFERENCE_ID,
      NAME_OF_TRADE_PARTY_1 COUNTERPARTY_NAME,
      ACTION INPUT_MESSAGE,
      REPORTING_TIMESTAMP REPORTING_TIMESTAMP,
      MSG_STATUS SDR_STATUS,
      COLL_PORTFOLIO_CODE_PARTY_1 COLL_PORTFOLIO_CODE,
      CORRECTION_STATUS CORRECTION_STATUS_CODE      
    FROM TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_TRANS_OP OP,
      TB_ETD_ENUMERATION EN
    WHERE OP.REPORTING_PARTY  = EN.NAME
    AND ( OWN_OR_DEL_REP NOT IN ('DD')
    OR OWN_OR_DEL_REP        IS NULL )
    AND REPORTING_PARTY IN
    (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )

    AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE('11-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP <= TO_DATE('14-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')

    UNION ALL
    SELECT MARRS_MSG_ID,
      OWN_OR_DEL_REP,
      ACTION,
      UTI_VALUE UTI,
      EN.DESCRIPTION REPORTING_PARTY,
      OP.REPORTING_PARTY REPORTING_PARTY_CODE,
      PRIMARY_ASSET_CLASS ASSET_CLASS,      
      TRADE_PARTY_INTR INTERNAL_TRADE_REF_ID,
      TRANSACTION_REFERENCE_ID TRANSACTION_REFERENCE_ID,
      NAME_OF_TRADE_PARTY_1 COUNTERPARTY_NAME,
      LIFECYCLE_EVENT INPUT_MESSAGE,
      REPORTING_TIMESTAMP REPORTING_TIMESTAMP,
      MSG_STATUS SDR_STATUS,
      COLL_PORTFOLIO_CODE_PARTY_1 COLL_PORTFOLIO_CODE,
      CORRECTION_STATUS CORRECTION_STATUS_CODE      
    FROM TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_POS_OP OP,
      TB_ETD_ENUMERATION EN
    WHERE OP.REPORTING_PARTY  = EN.NAME
    AND ( OWN_OR_DEL_REP NOT IN ('DD')
    OR OWN_OR_DEL_REP        IS NULL )
    AND REPORTING_PARTY IN
    (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )    
    AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE('11-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP <= TO_DATE('14-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')

    ) INNER_QRY   ) WHERE RN >= '1' AND RN   <= '20'
```

**We have index on REPORTING_TIMESTAMP**

Below is execution plan, looks ok to me, still fetching only 20 records taking 3 min.

[image: ExceutionPlan]

Comment: Explain plan is incomplete.

Comment: I am not able to attach execution plan image

Comment: In SQL*Plus, generate explain plan with proper formatting, copy paste using code tags.

Comment: Run the command: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query`, then run `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);`, and copy and paste it's results as a text.

Comment: run a trace/tkprof on the query to see the timings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple general hints:

1) Consider to rewrite this expression:

```
 AND REPORTING_PARTY IN
    (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )
```

as following:

```
 AND instr(','||:comma_separated_values||',', ','||REPORTING_PARTY||',') > 0
```

or in your case without bind:

```
 AND instr(',HONGKONG,SINGAPORE,JERSEY,', ','||REPORTING_PARTY||',') > 0
```

2) consider to replace

```
OWN_OR_DEL_REP NOT IN ('DD')
    OR OWN_OR_DEL_REP        IS NULL
```

with :

```
NVL(OWN_OR_DEL_REP,'?') NOT IN ('DD')
```

3) try to get rid of nested loops (use hint `use_hash`)

Comment: Thanks, let me try this